# fading out text label as well as nodes in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a filter function which fades out the rest of the nodes and highlights the selected set of nodes. I also want the labels associated to the nodes to reflect the same, i.e. fade out for the rest and only show the ones that are associated to the selected nodes. I have the following snippets:

```
// define properties of nodes
  var node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dataNodes")
    .attr('id', function(d){ return 'id' + d.id; });


  // define visual properties of node labels
 var text = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("font-size","6px")
    .attr("dx", 6)
    .attr('id', function(d){ return 'id' + d.id; })
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .text(function(d) { 
            return d.name;
       });


    function filterByName(relevantArray){

      d3.selectAll(".dataNodes").transition().duration(toggleTime).style("opacity", 0.3);
            d3.selectAll(".labels").transition().duration(toggleTime).style("opacity", 0.3);
            d3.selectAll(relevantArray).transition().duration(toggleTime).style("opacity", 1);

    }
```

The filter function is passed with a set of IDs which is used for setting the opacity of the nodes and labels. Since the ID of both the node and associated label is the same, why is only the node's properties getting affected by the function and not the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just answered your own question here:

> Since the ID of both the node and associated label is the same,...

IDs are **unique**. You cannot have two elements with the same ID.

Thus, set different IDs for the texts...

```
 .attr('id', function(d){ return 'idCircle' + d.id; })
```

And for the circles...

```
 .attr('id', function(d){ return 'idLabel' + d.id; })
```

However, in your case, to select both the circle and the text later, you can simply use `class` instead:

```
.attr('class', function(d){ return 'class' + d.id; })
```

Because, unlike IDs, you can have two elements with the same class and, therefore, you can use `selectAll` to select all of them:

```
d3.selectAll(".someClass")
    .transition()
    //etc
```